# Sqlalchemy joint filter with potentially empty child object list

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two classes in my code: a Person with the name and its Nicknames:

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
Base = declarative_base()

class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(10))
    nicknames = relationship('Nickname', 
                             back_populates = 'person')

class Nickname(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'nickname'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = Column(String(10))
    person_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('person.id'))
    person = relationship('Person', back_populates = 'nicknames')
```

I want to query a person where given **text** equals `Person.name` column or equals `Nickname.value`.
However, `Person.nicknames` list could be empty. Therefore, the following query ignores the persons with empty nicknames:

```py
query(Person).join(Nickname).\
              filter(or_(Person.name == text, 
                         Nickname.value == text)).\
              first()
```

To work-around this possible "emptiness" I construct a query as follows:

```py
q1 = session.query(Person).filter(Person.name == text)

q2 = session.query(Person).join(Nickname).filter(Nickname.value == text)

person = q1.union(q2).first()
```

Is there a way to pack two queries in one using joins?
I.e. to seach among the names first, and then to check all the nicknames if any.

Comment: I suppose an `outerjoin()` should do.

Comment: @IljaEverilä, you were right, thank you! Apparently it was a stupid question but my experience with Sqlalchemy is quite limited. I tried various flags in `outerjoint` and it did not work properly previously.

Comment: Though terse, my comment wasn't meant as a put-down, and I'm sorry if it came out that way. It's not a "stupid question", especially since knowing the short answer requires also knowing how OR acts in light of NULLs, and what to use to account for the "emptiness" on the other side of the join (use a LEFT JOIN). I refrained from writing a proper answer because I was looking if something similar enough had been asked and answered before here on SO.

Comment: @IljaEverilä maybe you could convert your comment into an answer?